# Set a GPO on all users from a trusted Forest

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

How do I set a GPO (such as desktop background) to work on users from Forest A when they connect to Computers on Forest B.

There is a bidirectional Forest Trust between the two Forests.

Answer (score 0):

See here: [Group policy features across forests](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737072%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

While older, it still is applicable on 2008 too.

> For example, User1 is located in forestA and computer1 is located in
>   forestB. User1 goes to forestB and logs into computer1. In this
>   scenario, computer policy is applied to computer1 from forestB, user
>   policy is applied to user1 on computer1 from forestA. Site policy
>   might be applied depending on the subnet to which computer1 belongs.
>
> For interactive logon across forests with loopback processing, Group
>   Policy objects with loopback enabled for merge or replace are applied
>   across forests under the same logon model as specified for interactive
>   logon.

So if your GPO for your desktop background is user specific, then a user from Forest A logging onto a computer in Forest B will get the GPO applied for their user account from Forest A still which would include the desktop background setting.

If the setting is computer specific, then they would get whatever computer specific gpo's are in Forest B for that computer.